# Querying xml with linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

So I am having a hard time understanding how to use linq in C#. I found some examples but couldn't find one that would match the case I am looking for. Given the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dwml version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http
://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://gra
phical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd">
  <head>
    <product srsName="WGS 1984" concise-name="time-series" operational-mode="off
icial">
      <title>NOAA's National Weather Service Forecast Data</title>
      <field>meteorological</field>
      <category>forecast</category>
      <creation-date refresh-frequency="PT1H">2013-09-18T07:17:35Z</creation-dat
e>
    </product>
    <source>
      <more-information>http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/</more-information>
      <production-center>Meteorological Development Laboratory<sub-center>Produc
t Generation Branch</sub-center></production-center>
      <disclaimer>http://www.nws.noaa.gov/disclaimer.html</disclaimer>
      <credit>http://www.weather.gov/</credit>
      <credit-logo>http://www.weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif</credit-logo>
      <feedback>http://www.weather.gov/feedback.php</feedback>
    </source>
  </head>
</dwml>
```

I want to print out the creation-date attribute value. The only way I was able to do this was by the code below:

```
XElement xElement = XElement.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)));
var nodes = xElement.Elements("head").Elements("product").Elements("creation-date");

foreach (var attr in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("value = " + attr.Value);
}
```

I am sure there is a much better way using queries. I tried playing with the select statements but couldn't get it to work correctly without having to do some manipulation. Would be really nice to just have one query without having to loop through the result set.

Comment: Your query is correct. What do you not like about it? If you don't want to loop through the result set, what do you want to do with the data?

Comment: I just didn't know if there was a better way to do this. I just know that the data is going to only be singular so I was hoping to avoid the extra effort since I will be doing this hundreds of times.

Answer (score 2):

```
String output=xElement.Descendants("creation-date")
                   .Select(x=>x.Value).First();
```

Comment: I still don't understand why almost everyone uses `Descendants` everywhere... [Why (or when) you should/shouldn't use Descendants() method](http://mjuraszek.blogspot.com/2013/08/why-not-use-descendants-method.html)

Comment: Thanks. So there is no way to query for that without looping through the result set?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek hmm..interesting article there by you..i totally agree with that

Comment: @Oros see the edit..am assuming that there's only one creation-date element

Comment: For those curious I took the advice @MarcinJuraszek and made it like so: var creationDate = xElement.Elements("head").Elements("product").Elements("creation-date").Select(x=>x.Value).First();

Answer (score 0):

That will give you collection of parsed `DateTime` objects:

```
var dates = from cd in xdoc.Descendants("creation-date")
            select (DateTime)cd;
```

You can enumerate them:

```
foreach(DateTime date in dates)
    Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Also if it is possible that other elements besides product can contain creation-date, then you can use following XPath to select creation dates of products only:

```
xdoc.XPathSelectElements("dwml/head/product/creation-date")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your values using `String.Join` method:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, nodes.Select(x => (string)x)));
```

But to be clear, it will perform collection enumeration anyway.